# Why delegate.respondsToSelector (Selector ("testEnum:")) this code will return false in swift language?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, respondstoselector

I was a few days ago from Objective-C to write Swift language, in the project I have encountered a problem.This problem is when using respondsToSelector ("testEnum:") function to check whether to implement the function of the testEnum:,if the param is the case, it will return false, I have tried other types, it will return true, do not know what is the reason, see the following code, to help me solve it, thank you very much!

```
 enum TestEnum {
        case A
        case B
        case C
    }

    protocol TestAProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
        func testEnum(testEnum: TestEnum);
        func testInt(testInt: Int);
    }

    class TestA: NSObject {
        var delegate: TestAProtocol?;

        func executeDelegateCallBack() {
            if (delegate != nil && delegate!.respondsToSelector(Selector("testEnum:"))) { // delegate!.respondsToSelector(Selector("testEnum:")) return false ?
                delegate?.testEnum(TestEnum.A);
            }

            if (delegate != nil && delegate!.respondsToSelector(Selector("testInt:"))) { // delegate!.respondsToSelector(Selector("testInt:")) return true ?
                delegate?.testInt(0);
            }
        }
    }

    class TestB: NSObject, TestAProtocol {
        func initTestB () {
            let testA: TestA = TestA();
            testA.delegate = self;
            testA.executeDelegateCallBack();
        }

        // mark TestAProtocol
        func testInt(testInt: Int) {

        }

        func testEnum(testEnum: TestEnum) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Its not the answer to your question, but your || should be && - You want delegate to be non-nil and to respond to the selector

Comment: Well, I'm writing a test example, not too much attention, thank you, I alter it!

Answer (score 6):

`respondsToSelector()` uses the Objective-C runtime and works only with
methods which are Objective-C compatible. Swift `enums` can only be
represented in Objective-C if they are marked with `@objc`, and that
requires that they have an integer raw value.

So with

```
@objc enum TestEnum : Int {
    case A
    case B
    case C
}
```

your `respondsToSelector(Selector("testEnum:")` will return `true`.

Note however that testing for the presence of a method makes only
sense with *optional* protocol methods, and these are only available
for `@objc` protocols, for example:

```
@objc enum TestEnum : Int {
    case A
    case B
    case C
}

@objc protocol TestAProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    optional func testEnum(testEnum: TestEnum)
    func testInt(testInt: Int)
}
```

And then it is much simpler to use optional chaining instead of 
`respondsToSelector`:

```
func executeDelegateCallBack() {
    delegate?.testEnum?(.A)

    // ...
}
```

or more detailed:

```
func executeDelegateCallBack() {
    if let testEnum = delegate?.testEnum {
        testEnum(.A)
    } else {
        print("delegate is `nil` or does not respond to `testEnum`")
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I was about to post the same... One little correction: the TestAProtocol is not required to be ObjC-compatible (at least in Swift 2.0).

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan: It is required for `optional` methods (at least in my Swift 2.1).

Comment: Now I see. From the optionality point of view, you are right. I meant that it's not required for the respondsToSelector: to operate.